# Totally ordering the rationals with an injective function.

Tags: field-theory, order-theory

I know that the rational numbers form an ordered field, but I would like to order them differently.

If I use the function $f:Q->Q$, where f(x)=$\ \begin{cases} 
      0 & x=0 \\
      1/x & x\neq0 \\ 
   \end{cases}
$

and then following the naturally induced ordering $x_1<x_2$ iff $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$, will this effectively re-order the rationals?

I have read that ordered fields are ordered "linearly." Intuitively, I think of this as just viewing the elements from least to greatest on the real life, from -$\infty$ to $\infty$.

In the perspective of the new ordering created by the function, will this intuition be translated as , in order of least to greatest, 
(0,-$\infty$), {0}, ($\infty$,0)?

I apologize for the abuse of notation here.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One of the axioms of an [ordered field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field) is:

For any $a,b,c$, if $a\le b$, then $a+c\le b+c$.

However, taking $a=-1, b=-3, c=2$, we get a problem with your proposed ordering.  $a\le b$, since $\frac{1}{-1}\le \frac{1}{-3}$.  However, $a+c>b+c$, since $\frac{1}{1}> \frac{1}{-1}$.

Hence, you have imposed a different total order, but that order does not respect the field axioms, so it is no longer an ordered field with this new order.

Comment: I see the problem. Would a better approach be to focus my attention on functions that are injective and continuous?